# parse and replace a list of object in kotlin

Tags: list, foreach, kotlin

I am currently having a list of obeject defined as:

```
fun updateList(tools: List<Tool>, updateTools: List<Updated>){
... code below
}
```

the `Tool` data class is defined as:

```
data class Tool(
    var id: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
    var assignedTo: String = ""
)
```

the `Updated` data class is defined as:

```
data class Updated(
    var id: String = ""
    var assignedTo: String = ""
)
```

Basically, I parse the list `updateTools` and if I found a `id` match in `tools`, I update the `assignedTo` field from the `Tool` type object from `tools` by the one from `updateTools`

```
fun updateList(tools: List<Tool>, updateTools: List<Updated>){
    updateTools.forEach{
        val idToSearch = it.id
        val nameToReplace = it.name
        tools.find(){
            if(it.id == idToSearch){it.name=nameToReplace}
        }
    }
    return tools
}
```

it's not working but I do not see how to make it easier to work. I just started kotlin and I feel that it's not the good way to do it
any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

- you're not assigning `assignedTo`, you're assigning `name`...
- in the predicate passed to `find`, which

  - should *only* return a `Boolean` value to filter elements, and
  - **should probably not have any side effects**,
  - those should be done later with a call to i.e. `forEach`.

Additionally, your constructor parameters to the data class are normal parameters, and as such, need commas between them!

Your last code block, corrected, would be:

```
updateTools.forEach {
    val idToSearch = it.id
    val nameToReplace = it.name
    tools.find { it.id == idToSearch }.forEach { it.assignedTo = nameToReplace }
}
return tools
```

I'd do it like this (shorter):

```
updateTools.forEach { u -> tools.filter { it.id == u.id }.forEach { it.assignedTo = u.name } }
```

This loops through each update, filters `tools` for tools with the right ID, and sets the name of each of these tools.

I use `forEach` as `filter` returns a `List<Tool>`.

---

If you can guarantee that `id` is unique, you can do it like this instead:

```
updateTools.forEach { u -> tools.find { it.id == u.id }?.assignedTo = u.name }
```

<s>`firstOrNull` returns the first element matching the condition, or `null` if there is none.</s> **Edit:** it seems `find` *is* `firstOrNull` - its implementation just calls `firstOrNull`.

The `?.` safe call operator returns `null` if the left operand is `null`, otherwise, it calls the method.

For `=` and other operators which return `Unit` (i.e. `void`, nothing), using the safe call operator simply does nothing if the left operand is null.

If we combine these, it effectively sets the name of the first element which matches this condition.

Comment: this is the most descriptive answer and thank you very much @moira

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing comma after properties in your data classes, so it should be:

```
data class Tool(
    var id: String = "",
    var description: String = "",
    var assignedTo: String = ""
)

data class Updated(
    var id: String = "",
    var assignedTo: String = ""
)
```

As for second problem, there're probably number of ways to do that, but I've only corrected your idea:

```
fun updateList(tools: List<Tool>, updateTools: List<Updated>): List<Tool> {
    updateTools.forEach{ ut ->
        tools.find { it.id == ut.id }?.assignedTo = ut.assignedTo
    }
    return tools
}
```

Instead of assigning values to variables, you can name parameter for `forEach` and use it in rest of the loop.